# How to re-throw the catched error in axios catch() block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux-saga

In `axios`, why `throw new Error()` is not allowed inside `catch()`?
I am in such requirement, where if an error is returned by the server, the catch block should throw an error, which later on will be handled by redux-saga and appropriate action would be dispatched.

The API call:

```
export const userSignupApi = userDetails => {
   const endpoint = `${URL_ROOT}${URN_SIGNUP}`;
    axios
    .post(endpoint, userDetails)
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Response: ", response);
      //do something with the response
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw new Error(error.response.data.message);
    });
};
```

I am getting `Unhandled Rejection (Error)` because of the above catch block.
Below is my saga which handles the operation:

```
import { call, takeLatest, put } from "redux-saga/effects";

function* handleUserSignup(action) {
  try {
    yield call(userSignupApi, action.userDetails);
    yield put(userSignupSuccess()); //dispatching success action
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(userSignupFail(error)); //dispatching error action
  }
}

function* watchUserSignup() {
  yield takeLatest(NEW_USER.SIGNUP, handleUserSignup);
}
```

Edit: Why I want the above code structure? Because this makes easy to unit test the API code and the saga code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. I was doing it completely wrong. As suggested by @certianPerformance and after reading some questions and github issues, I got the right way to handle this. Instead of returning the api response, I should have returned the `promise`.
**Here is the solution:**

```
export const userSignupApi = userDetails => {
  const endpoint = `${URL_ROOT}${URN_SIGNUP}`;

  return axios.post(endpoint, userDetails);
};
```

Saga:

```
import { call, takeLatest, put } from "redux-saga/effects";

function* handleUserSignup(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(userSignupApi, action.userDetails);
    response.then(response => {
      const location = response.headers.location;
      put(userSignupSuccess(location));
      put(newUserWelcomeNote("Welcome user"));
    });
  } catch (error) {
    const errorMessage = error.response.data.message;
    yield put(userSignupFail(errorMessage));
  }
}

function* watchUserSignup() {
  yield takeLatest(NEW_USER.SIGNUP, handleUserSignup);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Promise created in `userSignupAPI` isn't being used anywhere (it's not even being returned), so when an error is thrown inside `catch`, the Promise chain resolves to an (uncaught) rejected Promise, resulting in the error.

In the caller of `userSignupAPI`, you should `await` the call, so that the `try`/`catch` inside `handleUserSignup` will see the thrown error:

```
export const userSignupAPI = userDetails => {
   const endpoint = `${URL_ROOT}${URN_SIGNUP}`;
    return axios
    .post(endpoint, userDetails)
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Response: ", response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw new Error(error.response.data.message);
    });
};

async function* handleUserSignup(action) {
  try {
    yield await call(userSignupApi, action.userDetails);
    yield put(userSignupSuccess()); //dispatching success action
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(userSignupFail(error)); //dispatching error action
  }
}

function* watchUserSignup() {
  yield takeLatest(NEW_USER.SIGNUP, handleUserSignup);
}
```

(make sure that `call` returns the `Promise` returned by `userSignupApi`)

Comment: `yield await call(userSignupApi, action.userDetails);` is not even making an request to the server(`userSignupApi`).

Comment: What is your `call` function? It hasn't been defined in the code in the question

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention. It's provided by `redux-saga/effects`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this but didn't find an answer. This question is the first one I found.

I think it's perfectly valid to catch and re-throw an error to let it bubble up in specific cases, I do it all the time with observables for instance.

Anyway, what worked for me was just returning a Promise.reject(err)

```
 // inside a function block
 try {
    axios.post(endpoint, userDetails)
 } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === 409) {
       // for example convert to a 200 with an error message
       return { error: { message: 'oops, conflict!'} };
    }
    // this to catch the exact same error later on
    return Promise.reject(err);

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using `try catch` because you don't want to throw error in browser console you want to handle in `catch`. Throwing error in `catch` will remove its purpose.If you want to throw error remove `try catch`(which is not a recommended way)

**UPDATE**

For axios catch method catches any error thrown by api url. If you don't want to catch error and show it in browser, you can remove catch block or you can call the action which handles error. For more information about promise catch you can refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

Comment: Read the question again. It's not about `try catch`, it's about `promise` functionality in `axios`